# Twilio SDK pricing

Tags: twilio

I want to develop a web app using Twilio SDK 
It should have 
1) video chat
2) audio 
3) text chat
4) archiving of the session
other requirements 
1) screen share
2) cobrowsing

Could someone please guide what would be the licensing price for the same?
Also if someone has experience in web app development using Twilio please get back to me

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not sure what language you will be working with but you can [get started with Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/getting-started#setup-localmedia) using Android, iOS or JavaScript SDKs.

You will be able screen-share using the `LocalMedia` object that collects audio and video captured from the local device's microphone, camera, or screen-share.

2) Using the [Programmable Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk) you can build audio into the app as well.

3) Programmable Chat and its core capabilities listed [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat) will help you build in app chat.

For pricing inquires, I suggest you reach out to [support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) directly.